# compare a value with a vector value

Tags: c++, vector

Can i compare a int value with a vector value?

I'm trying to search if the user input a no, match the vector id no

```
int no;
cout << "Input a no";
cin >> no;    

for (int n=0;vector.size();n++){

if(no==vector[n].getID()){

...

}

}
```

Comment: What problem with that code are you having? By the way, I recommend `std::find_if`.

Comment: For the comparison part, assuming what is in your vector has a `getID()` that returns a type of the same type as `no`, I'd say looks fine. There are some other problemsm but you haven't asked about those - and of course, it may be all wrong because of something that ISN'T in your post

Comment: @MatsPetersson getID() return a value, i'm trying to compare if the user input the value match with the vector ID value

Comment: Right, so you may need to explain a little more what is not working...

Comment: @user1745860, Again, what about the code you have isn't working? It would be a lot easier to tell with a short, complete sample.

Comment: @MatsPetersson my mistake, ive shd have declare it as string at first...

Comment: @chris it was some declaration fault.. ive sorted it out

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 You can use `find_if` with a *lambda function* to detect matching ID, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct user {
    int userid;
    string name;
    user(int id, string n) : userid(id), name(n) {}
};

int main() {
    vector<user> v;
    v.push_back(user(1, "quick"));
    v.push_back(user(2, "brown"));
    v.push_back(user(3, "fox"));
    v.push_back(user(4, "jumps"));
    auto needId = 3;
    // Here is the part that replaces the loop in your example:
    auto res = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [needId](user const& u) {
        return u.userid == needId;
    });
    // res is an interator pointing to the item that you search.
    if (res != v.end()) {
        cout << res->name << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This prints `fox`, as expected ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/QobAnJ)).

Comment: You can also make use of an initializer list to initialize the vector :)

Comment: @chris I think that's too much C++11 for an early-stage exercise, but you're absolutely right - that's what I'd use in my "real" code.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I'm presuming by no. you mean number. So what happens with cin is that you get a String. This then needs to be converted to an int be compared to a vector, which is what I presume you are using. Then, just compare the noAsNumber to the vector[i] value.

```
string no;
int noAsNumber = atoi(no.c_str());

int i;
for (i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `cin` doesn't necessarily give a string, it can give an `int` just as well.

Comment: Ah, I never realised that. That could have saved me a lot of headache :)

Comment: And if you got a string, you'd have to **convert** it to an integer value. There is no cast that will do that.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm not quite sure what you're saying? The atoi() function does convert a const char* to an integer.

Comment: "This then needs to be **cast** to an int"; There is no **cast** that will convert the contents of a string into an integer value. `atoi` is **not** a cast, it's a function.

Comment: `atoi` takes a `char*`, assumed to be a null terminated string, and returns an integer.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sorry, I must have typed the wrong thing. I meant convert, thanks for pointing out my error. I'll type more carefully next time.